# Error 1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: EncryptedLocalStore

Tags: actionscript-3, air

I'm getting the error even though the import is not throwing errors:

```
1046: Type was not found or was not a compile-time constant: EncryptedLocalStore.
```

Here is my code:

```
import flash.data.EncryptedLocalStore;

var str:String = "Bob";
var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
bytes.writeUTFBytes(str);
EncryptedLocalStore.setItem("firstName", bytes);

var storedValue:ByteArray = EncryptedLocalStore.getItem("firstName");
trace(storedValue.readUTFBytes(storedValue.length)); // "Bob"

EncryptedLocalStore.removeItem("firstName");
```

I've checked and EncryptedLocalStore was introduced in AIR 1.0 (or 3.0). I'm using AIR 3.6. I'm also using this in a library project.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange. I was somehow able to get rid of the errors by doing the following:

- Clean
- Restart
- Select Include Adobe AIR libraries in the Project Properties > Compiler settings
- Add -swf-version=19 to compiler arguments
- Clean
- Choose Use minimum Flash Player version
- Clean
- Change to different SDK
- Clean project.

NOTE: It's working at this point. I then reversed back through those changes and after doing the following it still works.

- Change back to original SDK
- Clean
- Uncheck Include Adobe AIR libraries in the Project Properties > Compiler settings
- Clean
- Remove -swf-version=19 from compiler arguments
- Clean
- Remove Use minimum Flash Player version and enter Flash Player 15.0.0

I'm back to where I started but now it's working?

**UPDATE:**
OK I figured it out:

1. Select "Include Adobe AIR libraries"
2. Switch SDK (Clicking apply doesn't work)
   Errors should go away
3. Switch back to previous SDK